# JSP read request body received from http request

Tags: java, jsp, http

In the API documentation it says

> By default, the results of the request lookups are available in the body of the  response in a line-by-line, key=value format. For example, a typical result may be formatted as follows:
>
> `--START:447777777777 status="ok" mcc="234" mnc="02"`
>   `operatorname="O2" isoalpha3code="GBR" END:447777777777--`

So, I sent request to

```
http://api.txtnation.com/Networks/Lookup?username=user123&password=pwd123&
msisdn=447766551112

String addParam=java.net.URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                        + "="
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")
                        + "&"
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")
                        + "="
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
                        + "&"
                        + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("msisdn", "UTF-8")
                        + "="
    + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(msisdn, "UTF-8")

java.net.URL msisdnLookup= new java.net.URL("http://api.txtnation.com/Networks
/LookUp/?"+addParam);

java.net.HttpURLConnection mmpostback = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) 
msisdnLookup.openConnection();
mmpostback.setDoOutput(true);
mmpostback.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

It shows me HTTP response :OK

```
System.out.println(mmpostback.getResponseMessage());
```

But the following shows me NULL..

```
status=request.getParameter("status");
mcc=request.getParameter("mcc");
mnc=request.getParameter("mnc");
```

I even tried reading parameters and headers but I couldn't find the above names- status, mcc, mnc, operatorname,isoalpha3code

How can I read the request body in jsp? Please suggest

Comment: Using logic in the JSP page is highly discouraged. You should have a DAO or some controller.

Comment: @RobinJonsson.. but this is not the comment I want.. how to read the above which comes in request body?

Comment: even after your update your are still reading the request.  You need to read the response.

Comment: @user2310289        How to read?? please guide

Comment: see my updated answer. as you are using URLConnection use the getHeaderField method

Comment: @user2310289  Sorry, I appreciate your research, but these are not the things I want. I am not receiving those in QueryString..in API documentation it is clearly written .. the responses they send are included in body with key=value format...    I think getReader or getInputStream is the method that should be used.. but how to? I am looking at their example..

Comment: Yes if it is in your body you can use getInputStream() or getContent()

Comment: at whoever has downvoted this question.. Can you Please also write answer?? show your guts please.. then i would consider this question is useless!!!  The codes are all there..

Comment: @user2310289.. Yes now you are getting mee... but can you add the code .. with getInputStream or getContent or getReader... my jsp code is there

Comment: answer updated for you

Answer (score 0):

The request that you sent did not include the status parameter though.
if you tried again with username you should succeed.

```
request.getParameter("username")
```

Based upon your updated answer you should be looking at the Response not the Request.

From JSP, how are you sending the HTTP Request?  If you are using Ajax then you can get the response in a success handler.

If you are using something HttpClient then again you can get a process the response.

As per your update (using URLConnection) you can use the getHeaderField method

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField(java.lang.String)

If the data is in the body of your response then your can use URLConnection.getContent() or URLConnection.getInputStream()

Another alterative would be to use the Apache HTTPClient class which is a lot more flexible and easier to use IMHO.  see http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods.html

Comment: we are only allowed to send msisdn, user, pwd.. and they will respond us with those .. status, mcc, mnc in response body.. so how to read those?

Comment: so if they are in the response body they probably won't be in the request header.

Comment: Hi .. did you understand my question?? Why should I read my own parameters?? They send me the information about msisdn I send them in their HTTP URL...   and they send the information of that msisdn in Body.. not in HTTP header, not in query string.. So, how can I read the body part??

Comment: request.getParameter("username") is my own parameter sent to HTTP URL.. why should I read my own parameter.. !! I should be reading the response coming after I make reqest to this URL  http://api.txtnation.com/Networks/Lookup?username=user123&password=pwd123&
msisdn=447766551112

Comment: Also I have already mentioned in the question that.. request.getParameter doesn't work and throws NULL whenever I tried them to read the msisdn's   status, operatorname and isoalpha3code that are responded by HTTP URL after my request..  please read the question properly...

Comment: You are not Answering the question..you should have commented first or asked first before giving right answer.. if you give me right answer I will surely upvote you..

Comment: Request is what you are sending, Response is what you are getting back - be clear.  Please read my answer

Comment: ok, i have now added code also to better understand..  please read it again!!